# MediaSource does not support ogg audio?

Tags: javascript, media-source

`MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"')` return `false` - is it mean that I can not stream ogg as a response from POST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly what it means. The clients which return `false` for this condition cannot play this media type (older browsers, unsupported OS or client settings which prevent this).

For **streaming** OGG file formats you can definitly use `Audio.play();` on most modern browsers, but unfortunately [the `MediaSource` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) does not support streaming with POST request - you would have to use the classic streaming method, or download the entire source file as a whole and then play it.

Comment: So no way to stream ogg from POST?

Comment: By GET I can `new Audio(src).play()` and listen sound while it not fully downloaded, but if I need to play audio as a response from POST I need to convert this response to blob after that create URL and play - but I will hear the audio only after full file is downloaded: 6mb audio example `fetch('https://ia802607.us.archive.org/31/items/tom_sawyer_librivox/TSawyer_27-28_twain.ogg').then(r => r.blob()).then(b => new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(b)).play())`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I've done some more research and updated my answer, it seems that using `fetch` for the OGG blob object via POST is not supported in `MediaSource`.

Comment: What do you mean by `classic streaming method`?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich `Audio(src).play()`

Comment: But maybe is it possible to use XMLHttpRequest to stream ogg from POST response?